# Extracting Outlook part of Win 7 profile only

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, roaming-profile, user-profile

Where exactly are the Outlook configuration settings contained in a Windows 7 Office 2010 user profile?

I want to move a user from Win 7 Office 2010 to Win 8 Office 2013 but rather than keep the whole user profile I would rather start with a new Win 8 profile and just add back the Win 7 Outlook configuration if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key you need is: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles`

Comment: Worked in Office 2010 but just discovered that does not work in Office 2013, must be moved to a different place.  Anyone know where it has moved to in Office 2013, and more importantly how to import the 2010 hive into the correct place in 2013.